# Laragon Showing IIS Welcome Page Only

Tags: laragon

I've installed the latest laragon in windows 10, recently it was working but now it is only showing the IIS Welcome Page in all of my websites even if I created a new one for example a wordpress template and go to right click Laragon > www > test > this create a http://test.test/ but showing the IIS Welcome Page. Did I misconfigured something? It was working yesterday, and I'm new to Laragon.

Answer (score 0):

It seems someone is using port 80, I've changed port and now works.